# printCoefmat with integer columns

Tags: r

Is there a way to use the `printCoefmat` function in R on a matrix which contains integer columns (between the estimates, p values etc.)? Right now, it always prints those columns with two digits, but I would like them to be printed as integers. Or would I have to rewrite the function from scratch?

Consider this example:

```
col1 <- c(1.11, 2.22, 3.33, 4.44)
col2 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
col3 <- c(0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2)
mat <- cbind(col1, col2, col3)
printCoefmat(mat)  # works only when has.Pvalue = TRUE is set
```

Edit: Another example which fails even when has.Pvalue = TRUE is set:

```
c1 <- c(0, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0)
c2 <- c(0.63, 2.47, 3.06, 2.39, 1.13, 0.29, 0.03, 0.00)
c3 <- c(5, 6, 7, 6, 4, 2, 1, 0)
c4 <- c(0.6058666, 0.2101691, 0.3853061, 0.2549378, 0.4761259, 0.5609007, 0.9803975, 1.0000000)
m <- cbind(c1, c2, c3, c4)
printCoefmat(m, has.Pvalue = TRUE)
# third column printed correctly, first one not...
```

Comment: If you're talking about col2, it prints as an integer (no decimals) for me. Check that you haven't changed your default printing options.

Comment: Ah, right... But it doesn't seem to print it right when I leave out the `has.Pvalue = TRUE` argument. I will change the question accordingly.

Comment: Added an example where printCoefmat fails to print integer columns correctly regardless of arguments provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printCoefmat(m, has.Pvalue = TRUE,cs.ind=2)     
##      c1   c2 c3     c4
## [1,]  0 0.63  5 0.6059
## [2,]  4 2.47  6 0.2102
## [3,]  2 3.06  7 0.3853
## [4,]  1 2.39  6 0.2549
## [5,]  2 1.13  4 0.4761
## [6,]  1 0.29  2 0.5609
## [7,]  0 0.03  1 0.9804
## [8,]  0 0.00  0 1.0000
```

Basically, you have to tell `printCoefmat()` that column 1 is *not* a coefficient/standard error column, by telling it that column 3 is the only `cs` column.  (Or using `cs.ind=numeric(0)` works too.)

Comment: Thanks, both solutions work, and your last hint was my preferred solution.